# Building VB.Net application and assembly warnings

Tags: vb.net

Using VS 2017. VB.Net application.

If I do a full compile I get warnings as below:

```
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "4.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\System.Net.Http.dll] to Version "4.1.1.1" [D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.2\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "9.0.0.0" [] to Version "10.0.0.0" [D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.


1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2042,5): warning MSB3836: The explicit binding redirect on "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" conflicts with an autogenerated binding redirect. Consider removing it from the application configuration file or disabling autogenerated binding redirects. The build will replace it with: "<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2042,5): warning MSB3836: The explicit binding redirect on "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" conflicts with an autogenerated binding redirect. Consider removing it from the application configuration file or disabling autogenerated binding redirects. The build will replace it with: "<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1.1" newVersion="4.1.1.1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />".
```

What is the correct way to resolve these issues? Thank you very much.

## Update

Based on the answer provided, here is my `app.config` document. I have removed all other assemblies referred to for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

So is the suggestion o delete these two `<dependentAssembly>` entirely from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the `System.Net.Http` and `Newtonsoft.Json` that you are referencing are using doesn't match with version of .NET your app depends on. Try removing the binding redirects from your app.config file. That will likely resolve the issue the next time you build.

**Update**

Based on the suggestions from your error message, you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Changing the versions of the two assemblies to 10.0.0.0 and 4.1.1.1 respectively. What I was proposing originally is to remove the `<bindingRedirect oldVersion...` element altogether so that it is not dependent on a specific version and can resolve for those libraries based on which version of .NET your application is using.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please see my updated question, as I want to ensure I understand your proposal. Or perhaps you can flesh out your answer with the methodology required to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had a look at your comments and edited my answer accordingly. Hope that helps.